# Signal analog sensor DHT22

Tags: microcontroller, adc, signal-processing, signal-theory

What is the change in humidity percentage for every Celsius degree change on a DHT22 sensor? I would like to know the value before it is converted into a digital signal.

For example, in temperature readings:

Here we convert 16 bits T data from binary to decimal system: 
0000 0001 0101 1111 → 351

Binary system Decimal system 
T = 351 / 10 = 35.1 ℃

What is the voltage value?

For humidity readings, here we convert 16 bits RH data from binary to decimal system: 
0000 0010 1000 1100 → 652

Binary system Decimal system 
RH = 652 / 10 = 65.2 %RH

What is the voltage value?

Comment: There is no voltage value, the numbers are calculated inside the sensor from a set of sensed, probably nonlinear raw values.